# single quote punctuation converted to question mark

Tags: html, special-characters

I am doing application with strut1.2. In UI, in html text box i am have provided value with single quote punctuation but stored in DB as ? mark. So how to handle the same.

Ex: ‘torana’ becomes ?torana?. Please advise me on the same.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, those aren't the ordinary single quotes, they're "smart" quotes, unicode code points 8216 and 8217. They are not in iso-8859-1. Maybe in windows-1252 or so. Try with `'\''` (code point 39) first, then if you _really_ want those "smart" quotes, check the _bytes_ that produces and try encodings like cp1252.

Answer (score 1):

Before Inserting the text field value into the DB,Once check the textbox value using replaceAll method
use like variable_name.replaceAll("\'","_sq_");
and then print that replaced string .If you entered ‘torana’ it need to change like _sq_torana_sq_ .
Otherwise you are getting something else

Comment: I tried the same. But its converted to ?torana? before storing in DB itself.So it seems its being converted while posting the HTML form values.is there anything i need specify in jsp page?

Comment: only single quote is problem for you then replace the ? mark with single quote like variable_name.replaceAll("\?","\'");

Comment: Naveen, we need to allow question mark also. that means how to find the question mark which is converted one or text itself has..?

Comment: Replace with <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  with <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> or try in another system